# Looking for a PHP Caching Library with multiple back-end storage adapters

Tags: php, caching

I am looking for a PHP caching library that has multiple back-end storage adapters. For example, something that can save the cache in a file or in Memcache.

Here are some of the libraries that I have found:

- [Extensible PHP Caching Library](https://github.com/jleider/extensible-php-caching-library)
- [Stash](https://github.com/tedivm/Stash)
- [RayCache](http://raynux.com/blog/2010/08/08/raycache-an-easy-multiple-configurable-php-caching-class/)
- [Zend_Cache](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.cache.html)
- [SabreCache](http://code.google.com/p/sabrecache/)

Comment: errm, you appear to have answered your own question? Whats wrong with the libraries you've found?

Comment: I'm the main developer of Stash- if you have any questions about it please let me know!

Answer (score 1):

PEAR also has two libs; [Cache](http://pear.php.net/package/Cache) and [Cache_Lite](http://pear.php.net/package/Cache_Lite). Both are not very current unfortunately and don't offer memcached backends.

Answer (score 1):

Zend_Cache is a pretty good library with a number of adapters and also easy to implement custom adapters. Zend is trying its best to keep its libraries current.

Answer (score 1):

Zend_Cache is easy to use & very flexible http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.cache.introduction.html

eg.

```
$frontendOptions = array(
    'lifetime' => 7200, // cache lifetime of 2 hours
    'automatic_serialization' => true
);

$backendOptions = array(
    'cache_dir' => './tmp/' // Directory where to put the cache files
);

// getting a Zend_Cache_Core object
$cache = Zend_Cache::factory(
    'Core',
    'File',
    $frontendOptions,
    $backendOptions
);

if (($result = $cache->load('myresult')) === false) {

    // cache miss; connect to the database

    $db = Zend_Db::factory(/* [...] */);

    $result = $db->fetchAll('SELECT * FROM huge_table');

    $cache->save($result, 'myresult');

} else {

    // cache hit! shout so that we know
    echo "This one is from cache!\n\n";

}

print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

My library which can work with APC, Memcache, Memcached and PHP Shared Memory: [PHP Memory Cacher](https://github.com/jamm/memory)